# Kendo grid connecting to Json dataset from WebAPI

Tags: json, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api, kendo-grid

Local IIS has WebAPI installed. Here's the asp.net MVC controller:

```
namespace MvcApplication3.Controllers
{
  public class AddressesController : ApiController
  {
    public IEnumerable<Address> GetAllddresses()
    {
        return MvcApplication3.Models.DatabaseAccess.getAddresses();
    }
  }
}
```

This is the Json returned:

```
[{"Id":57638,"Address_1":"1226 S STATE ST","Address_2":"","Zip":60605},      
 {"Id":57639,"Address_1":"1240 S STATE ST","Address_2":"","Zip":60605}]
```

Here's the grid:

```
 var AddressList = kendo.data.Model.define({
    fields: {
        Id: "Id",
        Address_1: "Address_1",
        Address_2: "Address_2",
        Zip: "Zip"
    }
});
$("#grid2").kendoGrid({
    dataSource: {
        transport: {
            read: {
                url: "http://localhost/api/addresses"
                dataType: "jsonp"
            }
        },
        Schema: {
            model: AddressList
        }
    }
});
```

Problem: The grid can't bind to the data

Comment: Can you elaborate on the problem some more? Does the method return the correct data? Do you get it back on the client side? Have you debugged your jQuery using Chrome? Is your API method ever even hit?

Comment: `Schema` should be `schema`. Also the model.id maybe should be defined as "Id". But I don't think they cause your problem. Can you give more details? Or even better, make a working jsFiddle example.